# I need convert or get javascript variable in php variable - lognormdist logpearsondist

Tags: javascript, php, statistics, distribution, converters

I need call javascript variable in php. You can see this code :

```
<?php 

        for($x=0; $x < count($payload); $x++){ 
          $datanya = $payload[$x];
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var mean = "<?php echo $mean; ?>";           
        var stdev = "<?php echo $standartdeviation; ?>";  
        var datanya = "<?php echo $datanya; ?>"; 
                
        var lognormdist = formulajs.LOGNORMDIST(datanya, mean, stdev, true);          

        </script>

        <?php 
        }
        ; 
// I wanna call variable javascript (lognormdist) here, as $lognormdist
?>
```

If need,
$payload is array of my data = [52.89, 68.03, 71.19, 86.02, 89.15, 89.84, 89.85, 103.37
111.17, 115.07, 115.18, 116.32, 123.72, 132.14, 181.27]

Function formulajs.LOGNORMDIST is from [formulajs.info/functions](https://formulajs.info/functions/)

or Anybody can help me with **PHP Code of LOGNORMDIST**, and also I need **LOGPEARSONDIST in PHP Code** :)

Comment: You can't. JS is client-side, PHP is server-side. To do what you're going for, you would need an AJAX call.

Comment: ohh sorry, I can't doing that. I didnt know how can I use AJAX on this problem. Do you can help me for the code?

Comment: It's a broad subject and I don't know anything else about your application, so it'd be difficult to say what the right approach is. You can check out MDN's [AJAX tutorial for beginners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: @El_Vanja - can you throw that into an answer so we can get an accepted answer on the question now that he knows his next step? I can see him not being the last person confused by that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @AlexH. Questions about this basic misconception are asked daily. The correct procedure is identifying a duplicate that would get the OP on the right path (your comment actually reminded me that I forgot that part). Answering this is hardly going to set any future readers on the right path, as the question is formed around some specific statistical functions.

Comment: Ouhh, sorry if I'm troublesome. But, i still learning, is about 1 month maybe.
If anybody know, please give me some code for Lognormdist Function & Logpearsondist Function? :)